# passing number_field_tag variable to rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my problem. I want to pass the value from number_field_tag to the rails controller through link_to.
here is a `view`:

```
<%= number_field_tag :quantity %>
<% link_to "do something", :controller => 'somecontroller', :action => 'dosomething', :pass_value_from_here => 'quantity' %>
```

and

```
controller:

def dosomething
   @ivar = Model.new(:quantity => :value_passed_from_link_to )
   # do somthing
end
```

Plus,
I am not trying to use `form`. I have some other params too to be passed through `link_to`.
for e.g.
`<%link_to "do something", :controller => "somecontroller", :action=>'dosomething', :pass_value_from_text_field => 'quantity', :some_other_value_from_some_other_model %>`
thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645153/submit-form-using-link-to-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use `link_to` here, you'll want to create a form which `submits` to your `somecontroller#dosomething` method.

You'll then find `params[:quantity]` populated with the input provided.

Something like this:

```
<%= form_tag somecontroller_dosomething_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :quantity, params[:quantity] %>
  <%= submit_tag :quantity %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I know I can do it, but here the case is different. I have some other params too from some other model to be passed. so, I dont think submit and form will help me right now.

Comment: AFAIK, It's the only way to obtain a variable from your user without using a specific `GET` request or Javascript.

Comment: Answered in my previous comment.  What you're talking about is called `binding`, and you'll need to use Javascript for that.

Comment: isn't there any other method to pass the input parameter through url to the controller.

Comment: Yes, via a `GET` request, but you have to _know what the value of `quantity` is first_ in order to do that.  You're trying to put the cart before the horse here.

Comment: Would you please explain it little further. Perhaps with a example.

Comment: A `GET` Request is something like `http://myserver/mypage?quantity=0` You have to know the value of `:quantity` in order to send that.  My understanding is you are trying to obtain that value from your users.

Comment: No, :quantity is user input and can be any thing.

Comment: Okay, so how would you send it via a `GET`?  You cannot -- unless you ask your user to specifically type it in the URL.  You cannot take it from an unsubmitted text_input_field and place it there.  It doesn't work that way.