# Rails: Redirect form_tag with radio button to 'show' page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm a rails noob, and no matter what I do, when I use my radio button I can't get it to redirect to where I want.

In short, I want to "show" the post id that the user has radio clicked when he clicks the submit button.

My feeble attempt so far is this (_searchresults.html):

```
<%= form_tag posts_path(:post_id), method: 'get' do %>
```

And then my radio button:

```
<td><%= radio_button_tag :post_id, post.id %></td>
```

And my submit_tag:

```
<%= submit_tag "Select Post", :name => nil, class: "button" %>
```

I want clicking that submit tag to go to this url:

localhost:3000/posts/10

^^^ where "10" is the post id of whatever post was clicked on the radio button.

Instead, it's going to this url:

localhost:3000/posts.post_id?utf=.&post_id=10

^^^^where utf equals a checkmark, not a dot, but I couldn't type that in

I don't understand why it won't go the URL I want.

Comment: why are you not using `link_to` helper?

Comment: I don't really know what that is. I looked at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645153/submit-form-using-link-to-in-rails                                But it doesn't seem to do anything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to route to the `show` of a post, you can simply use `link_to` helper like this:

```
link_to "Show Post", post_path(post.id)
```